# Precise anchoring of shadows on entities

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, pyglet

I would have a question to ask, hoping for your advice. In my project I'm working on the different entities that will be present, one of them is the "TreeEntity". It is visibly composed of four parts. "Leaves, Shadow, Stump, Trunk". All four parts have only one id and are randomly chosen when a new "TreeEntity" is called. In addition, leaves and shadow each have four different states, based on the age of the tree. The shadow will have to rotate around the trunk based on the time. Now, since the engine of my project would like to create it as universal as possible, so that it can also be used in other projects or other people, I am facing a dead end.

I have this result at the moment (premise, all the images used are for testing purposes only):

[image]

As can be seen, the shadow is very detached from the trunk. This, theoretically, would be possible to fix it, modifying the image used:

[image]

Or write a huge dictionary with all the precise anchors written for each image that make up leaves, shadow, stump and trunk.

But doing so would be detrimental to my goal. So, the advice I would like to ask you, is whether in pyglet or otherwise, regardless of the shadow used (which in this case is random) is it possible to choose an anchor point that places it in the right place? Or do you have to modify the image or create a dictionary?

My question arises from the fact that I have seen several times images for example of shadows or something else that is like the one I inserted here, but in that case the shadows were in their correct place. The same game from here I took the pictures to test and I'm inspired by one or two mechanics has the shadows placed in the right place. So I don't know which way to go sincerely.

At the moment, all four parts have a universal anchor dictated by a small dictionary:

```
__statdict = {
        "leaves": {
            "cell": (3, 1),
            "anchor_x": "center",
            "anchor_y": "bottom"
        },
        "shadow": {
            "cell": (4, 1),
            "anchor_x": "left",
            "anchor_y": "bottom"
        },
        "stump": {
            "cell": (1, 1),
            "anchor_x": "center",
            "anchor_y": "bottom"
        },
        "trunk": {
            "cell": (1, 1),
            "anchor_x": "center",
            "anchor_y": "bottom"
        }
    }
```

And when loading resources, anchor is assigned:

```
if self.__statdict[name]["anchor_x"] == "center":
    ancx = texture.width // 2
elif self.__statdict[name]["anchor_x"] == "right":
    ancx = texture.width
else:
    ancx = 0
if self.__statdict[name]["anchor_y"] == "center":
    ancy = texture.height // 2
elif self.__statdict[name]["anchor_y"] == "top":
    ancy = texture.height
else:
    ancy = 0
texture.anchor_x = ancx
texture.anchor_y = ancy
```

I have tried to be as complete as possible. Thanks for your help. Maybe maybe I'm having problems for nothing and the solution is simpler than I thought, so I apologize if this were the case.

Update (1):

Is it possible, via pyglet or a module to accompany it, given the direction of a sprite (in this case on the right), to know what is the position of the first pixel that is not an alpha? Something like this: "The direction of the SpriteShadow is to the right. The first pixel that has an rbg value with alpha equal to 255 is ay = 20 (relative to the width of the sprite). Then I move the SpriteShadow to the left with respect to the general anchor of 20 pixels "

Comment: I don't see any other way around this than to modify the anchor point to match in both the entity and the shadow map. Unless you write shaders and "automatic" parsers for custom shadoes, but that goes away from the whole images as sprites idea. But I don't see how this could be solved in any other way than having a pre-defined "source x,y" that is known in each source data. Best bet would be to re-arrange all the images so that the trunk precicely match up in all images (both source and shadow), and thus easier to align. I could be wrong and welcome someone to post a different answer :)

Comment: I thank you for your answer. I only realized now that in the universal anchor dictionary, I was wrong in writing "anchor_y": "bottom" instead of "anchor_y": "center". While this mistake of mine repositions the shadow a little closer, it still remains detached. I got an idea that I will add to my question, but I don't know if it is feasible in any way.

Comment: I would position the tree end and shadow end, at the very bottom and dead center of the image. Then I'd calculate the `y_offset` for each model and add that. That should give you a rotational-friendly position of the sahdow. It's important that the shadow and the original resource share a common center origin of rotation, but the coordinates might be different depending on if the shadow is distorted or not. The simplest example would be this: https://i.imgur.com/ac11nW6.png - Where if you take the `y_offset` into consideration, both are free to rotate along the anchor point. Simplified that is

Comment: Regarding your edit, pyglet does support getting raw data via https://pythonhosted.org/pyglet/api/pyglet.image.ImageData-class.html - which you can use to identify the alpha range (0-255) of the `rgba` pixel data pairs. If that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. At the moment I have changed the type of image to use and its layout. This is because the images of the tree and its shadows did not allow me to do as you suggested. I went close to the realization (even moving the shadow of its x and y axis as it rotated) but it never convinced me, so at the moment I dismissed the idea. However, if you want, I can give you a better answer if you also write two lines XD